# Text in Rstudio terminal is messed up / distorted

Tags: terminal, rstudio, settings

A few days ago suddenly terminal output became distorted as you can see in the below image.
Do you have any idea why it happened? I appreciate any helps.
[image]

Comment: Would send that to RStudio as an issue

Comment: @Phil Though maybe it's somethign in the settings.